# Firebase - Can you limit Realtime Database data usage per authenticated user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to make sure that a single Firebase authenticated user only uses a certain maximum data usage. This is to limit ahead of time the potential damage of an accidental db call that gets into an infinite loop or damage by a malicious user.

Comment: It is possible to rate limit users through Firebase security rules. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40308318/firebase-rate-limiting-in-realtime-database-rules-language